# Applying a decorator to all methods of a derived subclass

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, subclass

I have a specific class, which is quite general, and I want to derive another class, where the a command is run before the class methods.

The path I chosen to follow is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55035043/1424118 . I tried many other, but I felt that I understand how it works. Well, here was I wrong as well.
My understanding was that the process is as follows: 1) create a subclass, 2) get all callable methods of the base class, 3) overwrite these methods with their decorated version.

My code is:

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def deco_func(func): #, channel):      
    @wraps(func)
    def new_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print("Decorator func.")
        return func(*args,**kwargs)                
    return new_function  

print("checking the operation of the decorator function")
def sq(a):
    print(a**2)
sq2 = deco_func(sq)
sq(1.1)
sq2(1.3) # yep, sq2 works


class my_class():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def square(self):
        self.a = self.a**2
        print(self.a)

class my_subclass(my_class):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # go over all elements in my_class and if it is callable, apply the
        # decorator function
        for attr_name in my_class.__dict__:
            attr = getattr(self, attr_name)
            if callable(attr) and a:
                print("Callable method found: %r" % attr_name)
                setattr(self, attr_name, partial(func, attr))

class my_subclass2(my_class):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # go over all elements in my_class and if it is callable, apply the
        # decorator function
        for attr_name in my_class.__dict__:
            attr = getattr(self, attr_name)
            if callable(attr) and a:
                print("Callable method found: %r" % attr_name)
                setattr(self, attr_name, partial(deco_func, attr))


print("\nOriginal class:")
a = my_class(1.05)
a.square()
a.square()
print("Supposed to be 1.05^4: %r" % a.a)
print("\nFirst subclass version:")
b = my_subclass(a=1.07, func=deco_func)
b.square()
b.square()
print("Supposed to be 1.07^4: %r" % b.a)
print("\nSecond subclass version:")
c = my_subclass2(a=1.03)
c.square()
c.square()
print("Supposed to be 1.03^4: %r" % c.a)
```

The output is:

```
checking the operation of the decorator function
1.2100000000000002
Decorator func.
1.6900000000000002

Original class:
1.1025
1.21550625
Supposed to be 1.05^4: 1.21550625

First subclass version:
Callable method found: '__init__'
Callable method found: 'square'
Supposed to be 1.07^4: 1.07

Second subclass version:
Callable method found: '__init__'
Callable method found: 'square'
Supposed to be 1.03^4: 1.03
```

The issue is that `b.square()` and `c.square()` return a function object, but I do not see why. I expect c.square() to be the same as deco_func(my_class.square()), which is sq2(). The obvious questions are where am I wrong, why did the decorated class function return another function, and how could I overcome this problem?

I use python 3.6.9.

Comment: Instead of having the child implement the parents method. Have the child implement a method the parent uses. So have  the parent  implement `square()` which uses `_square` and have the child implement the `_square` method....

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the function partial() break the code. Below is an MWE, which works. Unfortunately I was not able to add an argument to the decorator, but I can live with that at the moment.

```
from functools import wraps, partial
import inspect, types

def deco_func(func):       
    @wraps(func)
    def new_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print("Decorator func.")
        return func(*args,**kwargs)                
    return new_function  

class my_class():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def square(self):
        self.a = self.a**2
        print(self.a)

class my_subclass(my_class):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for attr_name in my_class.__dict__:
            attr = getattr(self, attr_name)
            if callable(attr) and attr_name[0:2] != "__":
                print("Callable method found: %r" % attr_name)
                setattr(self, attr_name, deco_func(attr))


print("\nOriginal class:")
a = my_class(1.02)
a.square()
a.square()
print("Supposed to be 1.02^4=1.082: %r" % a.a)

print("\nSubclass version:")
b = my_subclass(a=1.01)
b.square()
b.square()
print("Supposed to be 1.01^4=1.04: %r" % b.a)
```